# Laravel Queues and FirstOrNew

Tags: laravel, laravel-queue

I'm using Laravel's queue to retrieve data from API, when I'm being notified about changes through Webhooks. Webhook returns only id of the changed object, so I need to make a request to API to get the rest.

I dispatch the job to get the object by id, it runs in background (redis driver, supervisor). In queue I use:

`Model::firstOrNew(['remote_id' => $id]);`

but on `->save()` I receive:

> SQLSTATE[23000]: Integrity constraint violation: 1062 Duplicate entry 'tag-12' for key 'categories_type_remote_id_unique' (SQL: insert into `categories`...

If I debug this code using `sync` driver I can't reproduce this error, it only appears in background jobs. Like the job can't get the most recent data from DB and uses the `new` part of `firstOrNew` instead of `first`

Answer (score 0):

the problem is for mysql .
you are entering duplicate entry 'tag-12'
find which keys you defined as unique . then change your firstOrNew method

Comment: `findOrNew` doesn't create anything in db, this happens on `save()`, and `findOrNew` should find the existing record in DB, but it doesn't